# encountering String was not recognized as valid datetime using ParseExact

Tags: c#

I want to insert the `DateTime.Now` as dd-MMM-yyyy format, but it is giving me string is not recognized as valid datetime while I use `ParseExact`.

```
db.AddInParameter(objdbCommand, "@dtAddedOn", DbType.DateTime, DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now), @"dd-MMM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

I have also tried :

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now), @"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

but it is giving me the same error

Comment: Try to output what `Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now)` is giving you ... also, why turning it into a string and then parse it back? That's totally unnecessary.

Comment: Why are you converting it, surly you just want to use DateTime.now, as a datetime as it is, why put it as text and tell the compiler you're sending datetime

Comment: _"I want to Insert the DateTime.now as dd/MMM/yyyy format"_ `DateTime` _has no format_. It's a number (basically).

Comment: 30-10-2019 17:27:09 @fildor it is giving me this

Comment: How did you get that output?

Comment: Convert.ToString(DateTime.now );

Comment: conversion is needed because ParseExact demands String value and not datetime value

Comment: You don't need ParseExact, neither. Just pass DateTime.Now.

Comment: Try: `db.AddInParameter(objdbCommand, "@dtAddedOn", DbType.DateTime, DateTime.Now);`

Comment: thank you it is working

Comment: reason what Fildor and I said worked is datetime is not a string, therefore it has no "format" it is a binary value

Comment: You meant to try DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), @"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), which is pointless/inefficient. @Fildor has a better answer. Convert.ToString is probably using your default CultureInfo, thus the mismatch. If you want to strip the date part, just use DateTime.Now.Date instead of DateTime.Now. It was not clear from your question which one you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are inserting a DateTime anyway, you do not need to Convert to string and parse back to DateTime.

```
db.AddInParameter(objdbCommand, "@dtAddedOn", DbType.DateTime, DateTime.Now);
```

will do the trick.

`DateTime` does not have a format. Format comes into play as soon as you need a textual representation of the value that the `DateTime` represents. I also wouldn't recommend to use `Convert` for this but one of [`DateTime.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) overloads.

Edit:

If you do not want to include the Time part, i.e. insert the Date, only you can use `DateTime.Now.Date` (see [Date Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.8))  or even easier [`DateTime.Today`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?view=netframework-4.8). This will give you a DateTime object with Time components all set to zero.

Edit 2:

Mind that there are some inherent problems using `DateTime`, especially if your system is going to be used spanning different TimeZones. Going deeper into this would go beyond the scope of this answer, though. Just want to give you a heads-up.

You may want to checkout [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.8) and related Articles like [Choosing between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, TimeSpan, and TimeZoneInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime)